# Set difference of a table field in Splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

From a search I composed a table, let's call it **T1**, formed by two columns `table name, sourcetype`

Now I need to create a static, code generated table, call it **T2**, that contains all the expected values for the above mentioned table **T1**, hardcoded.
1st question: How could I?

2nd question:
As a result, I need to generate a table **T3** equal to: `T2 - T1`, basically a logical set difference of the first field, which answer the business question "I want to know which records are missing in T1 based on T2"

I am a newbie of Splunk and its query language and I tried to play a bit with `set diff` and `eval` to create static data but I did not manage to create the logic I want at all.

Could you point me to the correct logical implementation of this task?

I do script fluently in both SQL and Python, is there any kind of concept I could reuse to become more familiar with this query language?

Stupid graphical example:

### T1

| name | sourcetype |
| --- | --- |
| service_1 | acpt |

### T2

| name | sourcetype |
| --- | --- |
| service_1 | acpt |
| service_2 | acpt |

### T3

| name | sourcetype |
| --- | --- |
| service_2 | acpt |

Comment: Your hard coded table of expected values could be a lookup table so you could pipe your table to outputlookup and then you can use inputlookup to read it back in the comparison search.  You can either edit it using that same method or using https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/1724/

Comment: To return items not in a subsearch https://community.splunk.com/t5/Splunk-Search/quot-NOT-IN-quot-between-two-search-query/m-p/41642

Comment: Hi @JerryJeremiah, thanks for your suggestions. `| savedsearch _t1 envs=prd NOT [ savedsearch _t2 name=* | fields name| format I ]` adapted the solution provided in your links but I don't get the expected result. I just get all the results from the first search without the deletion of the elements in the second search. `sourcetype` doesn't play any role, I want to consider only `name`

Comment: I think the sub search needs to explicitly exclude _time and any other default fields otherwise they will be used in the NOT and of course the times won't match so nothing will be excluded.  What about `... [ ... | fields name | fields - _time ... ]`

Comment: Hi @JerryJeremiah, the last statement of both subsearch is `| table name, sourcetype` so I did expect not to have unwanted default columns, but I am going to try out soon anyhow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the question 2, you could use stats command and search the field which have only one count (so nothing common). It's like a grouped by.

```
|stats count by name sourcetype
```

After you search the count=1 to have the difference

```
|search count=1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I didn't get how can I feed to the command my two saved searches for instance?
`| savedsearch _table1 | savedsearch _table2`.

How do I pass to the content to stats command?
`| stats count by name`.
`sourcetype` does not play any role, I don't want to consider it

Comment: Thanks, worked for me. Sorry for the basic questions, those are my first days with Splunk at all :)

Answer (score 1):

This makes some test data for the events:

```
| makeresults count=6
| streamstats count
| eval name="service_".tostring(count)
| eval sourcetype="acpt"
| fields - count _time
```

| name | sourcetype |
| --- | --- |
| service_1 | acpt |
| service_2 | acpt |
| service_3 | acpt |
| service_4 | acpt |
| service_5 | acpt |
| service_6 | acpt |

And this makes a list of events to exclude:

```
| makeresults count=2
| streamstats count
| eval name="service_".tostring(count+2)
| eval sourcetype="acpt"
| fields - count _time
```

| name | sourcetype |
| --- | --- |
| service_3 | acpt |
| service_4 | acpt |

And this prints all the items in the first set that aren't in the second set:

```
| makeresults count=6
| streamstats count
| eval name="service_".tostring(count)
| eval sourcetype="acpt"
| fields - count _time
| search NOT [
  | makeresults count=2
  | streamstats count
  | eval name="service_".tostring(count+2)
  | eval sourcetype="acpt"
  | fields - count _time
]
```

| name | sourcetype |
| --- | --- |
| service_1 | acpt |
| service_2 | acpt |
| service_5 | acpt |
| service_6 | acpt |